# 2 auto roles for 2 different categories but only the fleet2 role is working

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

**i have 2 auto roles.
fleet1 role- is assigned to a user when they join "fleet1 category vc's"
fleet2 role- is assigned to a user when they join "fleet2 category vc's".
only the fleet2 role is being assigned to members when they join the fleet2 category. fleet1 is not working. anyone know of a solution?**

```
import discord
import config

from discord.ext import commands

class VoiceUpdate(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot: commands.Bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member: discord.Member, before, after):
        role = member.guild.get_role(config.FLEET1_ROLE)
        channels = [config.FLEET_1_ID, config.FLEET_2_ID, config.FLEET_3_ID, 
 config.FLEET_4_ID, config.FLEET_5_ID]

        for chnl in channels:
            channel = member.guild.get_channel(chnl)
            if member in channel.members:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                return
            else:
                await member.remove_roles(role)


    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_voice_state_update(self, member: discord.Member, before, after):
        role = member.guild.get_role(config.FLEET2_ROLE)
        channels = [config.FLEET_6_ID, config.FLEET_7_ID, config.FLEET_8_ID, 
config.FLEET_9_ID, config.FLEET_10_ID]

        for chnl in channels:
            channel = member.guild.get_channel(chnl)
            if member in channel.members:
                await member.add_roles(role)
                return
            else:
                await member.remove_roles(role)
    
async def setup(bot: commands.Bot) -> None:
    await bot.add_cog(
        VoiceUpdate(bot))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've overwritten the method, so only the second one works.

It's like this:

```py
>>> class MyClass:
...   def method(self):
...     return 'first method was called'
...   def method(self):
...     return 'second method was called'
... 
>>> a = MyClass()
>>> a.method()
'second method was called'
```

You need to name them different things in order to have them both register. [`listener`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=listener#discord.ext.commands.Cog.listener)

```py
    @commands.Cog.listener('on_voice_state_update')
    async def voice_update_1(self, member: discord.Member, before, after):
        ...

    @commands.Cog.listener('on_voice_state_update')
    async def voice_update_2(self, member: discord.Member, before, after):
        ...
```